# It possible to reformat Ubuntu Hard drive without Live Disk?

Tags: boot, partitioning

My sister just wants to reformat her laptop with Ubuntu and throw it away/electronic recycling.  I have no idea how ubuntu works and barely learned how to open the terminal.  I tried reformatting in various ways but it keeps giving me the "/dev/sdal" is mounted error.  And I know I cannot unmount it because that is where the operating system is being run.  Is there a way to reformat the hard drive without the live disk?  Any help would be appreciated.  Step-by-step instructions preferred.

Comment: Yes, but it can require a live cd of other OS'es anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format any disk that is ***not*** mounted.

On an active system you can also use `rm`, `dd`, `cp` and `cat`. Examples  (**Yes, these *will* kill your system** so you are warned (and yes I left the command needed in front of these out of them on purpose):

```
rm -rf /
dd if=/dev/urandom > /dev/sd{xy}
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/sd{xy}
cp /dev/urandom /dev/sd{xy}
```

There are more methods, you can use the utility [wipe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe), [shred](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html), the [badblocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/badblocks.8.html) command, or [scrub](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/scrub/).

{xy} are the device letter and number (ie. sda1, sda2 etc).

---

/dev/urandom is a bottleneck. I found this on [u&l from Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72238/10017) <3

```
openssl rand $(</proc/partitions awk '$4=="sda" {print $3*1024}') >/dev/sda
```

is very quick (it messes up a complete disk).

---

Alternative: you can also format a partition from the grub rescue prompt with fdisk and parted (parted is the command line version of gparted).

---

If the intention is to throw away the disk: the only good method is to hammer a nail through the disk. Formatting can be made undone, a shredding tool should be used since those do more than 1 run over the whole disk writing digits at random making it impossible to restore.

And to add to this: SSD's have a high failure rate in deleting data from a disk. The best erasing method for SSD's is ATA secure erase but this is buggy ([Paper related to this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/can-wiped-ssd-data-be-recovered): 12 disks, 8 have ATA secure erase, 3 of those had a buggy implementation and 1 reported the disk was cleared but the data was still there).

Comment: Definitely.  If you two are gun people, hard disks make excellent targets for smaller rifles.

Comment: Or larger ones...

Comment: Does `cp` work like that? I think it will replace the `/dev/sd*` device file with the file (literally), not the contents of the device. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX` (where `sdX` the disk name) should also work (no need to wipe a specific partition if you are discarding it anyway). As long as you don't do anything with a system, wiping a mounted disk should also work (but no guarantees of course :)). An existing system can be made readonly with `mount -o remount,ro /` (repeat it for other mount points).

Comment: yes it does. `cp` ignores the type of the destination. BUT I have not actually tried it >:=D Oh and this method seems to be quicker (dd is slow) where cat is almost as fast as cp. urandom is slow in itself too though. `openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero > randomfile.bin` is the quickest but a monstrosity :D

Comment: Can you provide a citation for "the only good method is to hammer a nail", or point to a data-recovery company that claims it can recover data from a disk wiped with one or two passes? For all practical purposes, [a single-pass wipe is good enough](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/5752/27444), especially if it's randomized instead of zeroed.

Comment: @200_success please point to where I claim a disk wiped (using a shredder tool) with one or two passes is recoverable? Oh and ssd's have a high failure rate in sanitizing a disk even with degausing: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf Only encrypting the data is a secure method to prevent restoration.

Comment: That's exactly what your last paragraph implies, though. If one pass were sufficient, why would you say that physically sabotaging the disk is the only good method, and why would you recommend using a shredding tool that makes more than one pass?

Comment: @200_success well it is a 100% guarantee. I added a link to a paper regarding sanitizing SSDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reformat the hard drive without booting to a different medium.

**There are alternative methods including gui resolutions**

For your information,while you might think it's hard, moving around the OS works much like Windows and the Mac, except I find it just a little easier.  In fact the Mac is basically Linux (Unix) with a Mac picture over it.  Microsoft Windows is growing more and more like Linux with every release.  You could remove the files from Linux much like you would in Windows.  Just click on the file explorer and systematically delete your sensitive stuff.  Your personal stuff is stored by default in your user space.  When you hit the File browser you'll be there.  You can systematically remove all your stuff from there.

Unlike Windows and other OS' all your personal stuff will be in your home directory or a sub-folder off it.  So removing your home directory will do it for all your personal information.

One easy way would be to create a new user.  Log in as that user, then remove the home folder of your sister's userID.

If you can do it in any other OS, you'd have a great learning curb for doing it on Ubuntu.  It's extremely intuitive.

Your object appears to want to remove the personal data from the computer.  The steps I provided would do this.  The description is to ease your mind of it being so much more different from what you are familiar with from the other environments.

Comment: @Fabby My answer addresses the content of the user's question.  He's flabbergasted at what appears to be an extremely foreign and complicates system.  If you read in more detail of his question you will find that he's specifically saying he has no idea how the system works.  I gave an idea and explained the ease.  If he looks at it again, he will likely see the system just like the one he uses personally and be able to prepare it for recycling the same way he would his machine... which his message appear to suggest he might be able to do.

Comment: OK...  I still don't see it, but that might just be me!  Up to the OP to decide...  (Downvote removed)